# What is the opposite of a 'baseline' on a graph?

Tags: data-visualization, terminology

The minimum value on the axis of a graph is the baseline. What would you call the maximum value? Topline?

[image]

Comment: personally I just call it "the maximum value on the axis". Its not like you'll need to say it 20 times.

Comment: "Baseline" has several meanings in this context, suggesting calling the minimum value of an axis the "baseline" might be unwise because many people will find its meaning obscure or will even misinterpret it.  What's the problem with using standard terms like "minimum" or "smallest" or "starting" value on the axis?

Comment: @whuber I saw the term baseline being used in one book on graphs. The problem I have is that it may be 0 or a minimum of one line but not the other so the word minimum seems like a subset of what a baseline can be. But after thinking about it for a day I think I might go with 'axis minimum' and 'axis maximum'

Comment: What book was this? I agree w/ @whuber: I wouldn't call that the "baseline". It's not a common usage that I've ever seen, & most likely will lead to misunderstandings.

Comment: @gnug Storytelling with Data: A Data Visualization Guide for Business Professionals (2015) by Cole Nussbaumer Knaflic. I deleted the book from my drive so I can't tell the page number. I liked the word baseline because it is less ambiguous than minimum to general audience since most people's first thought would be that minimum refers to data not the axis, even if you explicitly say 'axis minimum'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your specific question: I would (like Glen_b) call it 'the maximum value on the Y-axis' or the 'Y-axis maximum' for short, if I need to refer to it a second time.

I also agree with the comments about your usage of 'baseline'. It's non-standard and likely to be misleading. The 'minimum value on the Y-axis' (or 'Y-axis minimum') would be a better option.